# Recommendation letter advice

Tags: recommendation-letter

I'm soon going to apply to some M.Sc. in Europe and I asked my current supervisor at work - he was a professor until a couple of years ago - to write a reference letter for me. My function at the company is currently related to what he used to teach as a professor so I thought it would be a good idea to ask him. He accepted, but added that he is extremely busy as of now and suggested I write the letter myself, after which he will read it. 
My issue is I don't really know how to write a recommendation letter that doesn't sound like the student wrote it :). Any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

As Buffy mentioned the issue of student writing a LoR is contraversial. You can read more on this webpage. Apart from ethics, I would like to point out the practicality. You will be writing a LoR for the first time and it is about you. You will probably overthink about what to say trying to be humble and not to undersell at the same time. You probably won't have a good sense of which of your qualifications should be pointed out with regards to field you are applying. Overall, you will be doing something (writing a lor), first time away, in a way it was never intended, under less than ideal situation. The result will likely be "meh". I can make few suggestions.

- Ask if you can help your boss with his work so he will have some time for you.
- Possibly find another recommendationç
- Consider applying in a later date, giving your boss more time to work on a letter. (perhaps in the spring term).
- You also can try to get a third person (possible colleague) write you a recommendation and let your boss edit it. It might bypass *some* of the issues. Not all. Ethics are still questionable. But it is an option.

Answer (score 0):

First, I'll note that a number of people here think that this practice is unacceptable. I'm not that strong on it, though think your reservations are important.

The supervisor didn't have you as a student, presumably, so can't speak to many of the qualities you will need for graduate study. All he has direct knowledge of is your performance at the job and your work ethic. That can be important, but isn't enough. Make sure that you also have letters from academics who knew you earlier.

But, instead of writing a draft of a letter, you could just create a list of bullet points that include things that you want to remind the writer of. Things you did on the job. Contributions you made, some of which he may not be aware of. In this way you let the wording be his, but help assure that he doesn't forget the things you'd like included. It also eases his work load.

But, it would be good to check with him on this before you finalize it. You could, in fact, take him a draft of such a list, complete or not, and ask if it is enough.